# JQuery addClass working in a very odd manner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I have a form with 3 inputs: 2 text inputs for a Username and E-mail and a third password input for, you guessed it, a password.

I'm validating these input fields in JQuery and when an input is either empty or doesn't match it's format, it adds a class to the input with a red border. The code goes as follows:

```
if ($("input#username").val().length < 6) {
                $("input#username").addClass('input-error');
                next_step = false;
            } else if (!isEmail($("#email").val())) {
                $("#email").addClass('input-error');
                next_step = false;
            } else if (!isPassword($("#pwd").val())) {
                $("#pwd").addClass('input-error');
                next_step = false;
            }

            else {

                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
                next_step = true;
            }
```

It works perfectly with both Username and E-mail fields, and it also works if the Password field is empty, but even though it validates perfectly, the addClass() doesn't work if the Password doesn't meet it's requirements (At least one Uppercase letter and one number).

This is what the browser console shows:

[image: Console]

As you can see, it kind of adds the class, but then not really.
What is happening? If you need the HTML code and/or the CSS code, tell me!

Thanks for your attention!

**EDIT**
Here is the HTML and CSS as requested:

```
<fieldset>
                <div class="form-bottom">
                            <img src="img/gbsnlogo.svg" alt="GBSN Research" name="GBSN Research" width="50%" class="signupLogo" />
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username"><h1>USERNAME:</h1></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username..." name="username">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email"><h1>E-MAIL:</h1></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter e-mail..." name="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd"><h1>PASSWORD:</h1></label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password..." name="pwd">
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn-next btn-nav"><h1>NEXT</h1></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
```

and the CSS:

```
.form-control {
    height: 40px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.form-control:focus {
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0;
}
.input-error {
    border-color: #FF2859;
}
```

Comment: We need the HTML and CSS code to help you. As the console shows that the element definitely has the class, my guess would be that the rules in the `.input-error` class are not specific enough to override any styling you already placed on the element.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Edited the main question with the rest of the code. Please remember that it overried just fine on both text inputs and also on the password input when it's empty.

Comment: Please see my snippet - it is really useful to have a [mcve] especially when sometimes you find the error when you create one (using the `<>` button)

Comment: The error is most probably in your isPassword function. So show the code of that function. ;)

Comment: What do you mean by `it kind of adds the class, but then not really`? The console definitely showed it had added the class to the input.

Comment: @AnthonyC it doesn't, if you look carefully you see that it's index 0 doesn't have the class added.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

Please comment what is still not working if you have this kind of setup?

```js
function isEmail(email) { // dummy example
  return email.indexOf("@")>1;
}
function isPassword(passwd) { // dummy example
  return passwd.indexOf("x")>=0; // must contain x
}

$(function() {
  $(".btn-next").on("click", function() {
    $(".form-group input").removeClass('input-error');
    var next_step = true,
    user = $("#username").val(),
    email = $("#email").val(),
    pwd=$("#pwd").val();
    if (user.length < 6) {
      $("#username").addClass('input-error');
      next_step = false;
    } else if (!isEmail(email)) {
      $("#email").addClass('input-error');
      next_step = false;
    } else if (!isPassword(pwd)) {
      $("#pwd").addClass('input-error');
      next_step = false;
    }
    console.log(next_step);
  });
});
```

```css
.form-control {
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form-control:focus {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0;
}

.input-error {
  border-color: #FF2859;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <div class="form-bottom">
    <img src="img/gbsnlogo.svg" alt="GBSN Research" name="GBSN Research" width="50%" class="signupLogo" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username"><h1>USERNAME:</h1></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username..." name="username">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email"><h1>E-MAIL:</h1></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter e-mail..." name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd"><h1>PASSWORD:</h1></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password..." name="pwd">
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn-next btn-nav"><h1>NEXT</h1></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see from the image you posted

[image]

I can only speculate this is what happened.
The line `[input#pwd.form-control.input-error]` was evaluated immediately when it got printed to the console. So that mean at that time, the dom does have the class `input error` in it. However, when you expand it, the dom got re-evaluated again. And at that time, the dom's class `input-error` got removed, so you don't see it anymore. I was able to prove this by running `$('#pwd').addClass('input-error')` and `$('#pwd').removeClass('input-error')` in that order, image below

[image]

Based on that, I suspect you have another logic in the code that remove the class shortly after you have added the class to the dom, highly possibly `$(this).removeClass('input-error');`.